# Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError couldn't find lib.so

Tags: android, android-ndk

Recently `Crashlytics` has reported a crash from a `HTC One A9` `Android 7.0` device for an app that I'm working on.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError  nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.app.test-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]] couldn't find lib.so
```

I looked everywhere specially similar questions but could not find a proper solution to my case because the app supports 64 bit version of the native library too. (See `cmake` config below)

This is the first time that someone with this device has installed the app and I did not see any linkage error on any other devices before.

I'm actually not sure if it is looking for the native-lib in the mentioned paths in the posted error? If that's the case, why it does't look for the lib in the `lib/arm64-v8a` path based on my `abiFilters`?

Here is my `cmake` config inside the app `gradle`:

```
cmake {
    abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
}
```

How can this issue be solved?

Comment: Were you able to find solution for this issue ? We have similar issue on Galaxy J Core device only

Answer (score 2):

First off: If it is one crash incident, I wouldn't worry about it. Only if multiple users crash on it, I would prioritize it. Freak errors on Android happen, especially if you consider the quality of some of the devices.

I do not think it is a missing library on your end.

The actual problem is the really strange library name: **lib.so**

This is not a valid name you would expect in an Android NDK application. You always expect it to look for lib*xxx*.so

The fact that it does not, means that the library name got mangled, or not properly specified in the manifest file.

Look in AndroidManifest.xml inside the activity tag, for a [line](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/meta-data-element) like this:

```
<meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="xxx" />
```

Next, in your apk file, you will want to see the library listed as such:

```
lib/arm64-v8a/libxxx.so
lib/armeabi-v7a/libxxx.so
```

With xxx, as your app name, of course.

If the entries in APK or AndroidManifest are missing, the fault is on your end. If they are there, I would just suspect a bogus customer device, maybe suffering from running out of file storage, or something.

Comment: Oh thanks @Bram. Sorry about the misleading name! The name was actually libsomething as you mentioned. I changed the name to lib when I was hiding the credentials before posting here

Comment: Do you have four .so files listed in your APK? You can examine the contents on an APK with 'unzip -l' or AndroidStudio.

Comment: Well, about the bogus customer device, as reported by Crashlytics, there were a lot of space left off on the device .A lot more than I needed. You're probably right about the ignoring the issue. Right now I'm waiting to see if that is being reported again or not

Comment: For the created .apk of AndroidStudio yes. There are four libs. But I've uploaded a Bundle to google play so its theirs responsibility to package only the needed lib for that particular device